# Typescript: Array not storing objects

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to assign row object to an array from a check box click event. For this i have created a global array like below.

```
SelectedGrid: any[] = [];
```

At the moment of clicking it seems it going into the array, but when i checked the second checkbox 1st item is gone missing from the array.
May I know why that happens?

following is the function i call in check box click event.

```
public clickConditionRow(row, col, rowSelected) {

            if (rowSelected.isChecked) {
                    this.SelectedGrid.push(rowSelected);             


                console.dir(this.SelectedGrid);
                console.log(this.SelectedGrid.length);

            } else {
                console.log("Unselected ");
                var toDel = this.SelectedGrid.indexOf(rowSelected);
                this.SelectedGrid.splice(toDel);
                console.dir(this.SelectedGrid);
            }

            if (!this.rootScope.$$phase) {
                this.rootScope.$apply();
            }

// for print the values
            for (var y = 0; y < this.SelectedGrid.length; y++) {
                console.log("Element " + y + " = " + this.SelectedGrid[y]);
                console.dir(this.SelectedGrid[y]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: `this.SelectedGrid.splice(toDel);` <--- what is this supposed to do?

Comment: it is been put there to remove the unchecked item

Comment: Are you sure it does exactly that? Have you tried to make a little 3 lines script to verify that?

Comment: yes.. I tried that. Now I completely removed that section. just to focus on checked items. It seems it's not getting added still.

Comment: What do you mean "it not getting added"? `this.SelectedGrid.push(rowSelected)` <- it's added here.

Comment: when the second check box is selected, the first selected items details are disappeared from the array.

Comment: It's impossible with the code you provided (after you removed `splice`)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your bug (maybe you are overriding the array somewhere else?) but I see 2 potential problems and want to point them out:

1. Using `indexOf` with and object might not work and return -1 (see the code below)
2. `splice(toDel)` should be `splice(toDel, 1)` or it will delete all items staring from index `toDel` to the end of the array.

```js
const a = { id: 1 }
const b = { id: 2 }
const list = [ a, b ]

// This returns 1
console.log(list.indexOf(b))

// This returns -1
console.log(list.indexOf({ id: 2 }))
```

Comment: Thank you for checking on this.  Issue seems to be in the If section, not in the 'else' part. Because when the check box is selected it comes to 'if' section.